# C++11 smart pointers always instead of new/delete?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, new-operator, smart-pointers

In C++11 should we always use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead of `new`/`delete`? How is it with performance, are smart pointers much slower?

Comment: `unique_ptr` was designed to be a zero-cost abstraction. Learn to stop worrying and love the bomb.

Comment: How can we use smart pointers **instead of** `new` and `delete`. We have to use them **with** `new`, to avoid `delete`

Comment: @iammilind `make_shared` and I also use an implementation of `make_unique`. Of course that still uses `new` internally.

Comment: @iammilind yes I know, but you can't use delete without new, so I just wrote "new and delete"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unique_ptr` doesn't (isn't supposed to) have any runtime overhead whatsoever compared to using raw pointers. `shared_ptr` does have some memory and time overhead (how much depends on the implementation). The *practical* overhead here can easily be zero if you actually need something that behaves like a `shared_ptr` (that is, no other implementation you'd think of would be any faster or more memory efficient).

That is not to say you'll never use new/delete in your code, but it's not something you'll do all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer shared_ptr to handle the raw memory because-

1) It follows [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and [Counted body](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Counted_Body) idioms.

2) Object is guaranteed to be destroyed, memory is released even if exception occurs.

3) No more choas of deciding when to new/delete.

Comment: Point 2 isn't true. If one shared_ptr refers to an object containing a shared_ptr which refers somehow back to the first. You will have a memory leak. Edit: So you will still need to know what you're with or without the smart pointers.

Comment: Point 2 is true, cyclic references is a "valid" state. `shared_ptr` give you only that if `ref_count == 0` its call `delete`.